# Gitlab registry behind reverse proxy error parsing HTTP 404 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, reverse-proxy, gitlab-omnibus

I am trying to set up a home GitLab + GitLab container registry(VM ubuntu omnibus install) behind an Nginx reverse proxy(win10):
I took the Nginx config from here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/-/tree/master/web-server/nginx

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 5050 ssl;
  #listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;
  server_name my-gitlab.org; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  ssl_certificate /nginx-1.18.0/my-gitlab.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /nginx-1.18.0/my-gitlab.key;

  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;
    
    proxy_cache off;

    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_pass https://my-gitlab-IP;
  }
}
```

Opening GitLab on 433 works so does Docker login on 5050, but when I try to push or pull from the container registry :
Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""

**tried many suggestions changing the GitLab.rb file, but non-work without the Nginx-revseproxing it Docker push/pull works so I am pretty sure it's something in my Nginx config that is missing, but not sure what.**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

it appears I needed a separate server block for the registry

```
server 
    {
        listen 5005 ssl;    
        server_name  my-ip:5005;
        ssl_certificate      /nginx-1.18.0/my-ip.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /nginx-1.18.0/my-ip.key;
        location / 
        {
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_pass          https://my-ip:5005;
        }
    }
```

reverted back to default GitLab registry port